# visited link state

Tags: css

I'm having an issue when I try to set the visited state, it does not seem to work.
Not sure why this is happening as the hover works but the visited does not. Any ideas why not?

```
 #nav li:visited a{ 
        background:#6b0c36;
    }

    #nav li:hover a{ 
        background:#6b0c36;

    }
```

Comment: a tag has psuedo visited... but not sure about li....

Comment: While you can apply a hover pseudo state to just about any HTML element, you can not apply a visited pseudo element to anything but an anchor tag (how can you visit a li tag?).

Answer (score 2):

what about this:

```
#nav li a:visited{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
}

#nav li a:hover{ 
    background:#6b0c36;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`li` elements cannot match the `:visited` pseudo-selector (think about what that would even mean). Anchors have locations that can have been visited, so if you need to change the style on a visited anchor, use:

```
#nav li a:visited
{
  background: #6B0C36;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense but I tried #nav li a:visited and it highlights all the li tags at one time.

Comment: @Chapsterj, it sounds to me like you don't understand what the [`:visited`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) selector does. *Any* anchor that has a location that you have navigated to in your saved history will match the `:visited` selector. It is **not** a way of testing which page is currently active.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/Jc24Y/  as you can see you click one button and all get set to the visited state. My understanding is only one item should get set to the visited state. If I clear my history I click another button it adds a visited state to all of them again.

Comment: @Chapsterj, they all have **the same location**. read my previous comment.